# type checking that value is not one of several values

Tags: typescript, enums

In typescript you can use an enum as a type in order to ensure that a variable has a value that is within the enum. For example:

```
type children = "Andy" | "Bob"

export const func = (name: children) : void => {
...
};
```

However, I wish for functionality that ensures the value of a variable is NOT within an enum (or any other kind of collection). I know this can be achieved with simple if statements/for loops but I'm hoping that when the variable is not one of certain values, something like a type error will be thrown. Is there something like the opposite of an enum that I can use to check a variable name is NOT one of several values? In the above example, I would want it so that the value of `name` is ensured not to be `Andy` or `Bob`.

Comment: I intended the above code example to work when you call ```func('Andy')``` so I'll need to edit it - but in general I want to ensure the function cannot be called with ```Andy``` or ```Bob```

Comment: And what about `func(Math.random()<0.5?"Andy":"abc")`? What about `func(someUnknownStringThatMightBeAndyWhoKnows)`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJpYgN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (and you might want `type Children = "Andy" | "Bob"` in your question and change it to not mention "enum"s at all). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want - ```Charlie``` should not cause any issues

Comment: Please triple check those edge cases before I write up an answer.  You want to *reject* unknown strings, because they *might* be in the collection, right?

Comment: Yes I want to reject even in scenarios where the value might be in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript lacks *negated types* (of the sort implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but never merged into the language), so there's no specific type corresponding to "all `string`s that are not `Children`".  If there were you could write `type NotChildren = string & not Children` and then just have `(name: NotChildren) => {}`. Instead, we'll need to simulate them by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

The approach I'll take here is to observe that a generic type `T` that's been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` should be rejected if and only if there's *no overlap whatsoever* between `T` and `Children`.  That is, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` and `Children` should be [the empty/impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So let's make `func` generic in `T` and give `name` the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `(T & Children) extends never ? T : never`, which evaluates to `T` if `T & Children` has no overlap, and `never` otherwise:

```
type Children = "Andy" | "Bob";
export const func = <T extends string>(
  name: (T & Children) extends never ? T : never
): void => { };
```

The basic usage looks like this:

```
func("Andy"); // error;
// const func: <"Andy">(name: never) => void

func("Bob"); // error
// const func: <"Bob">(name: never) => void

func("Charie"); // okay; 
// const func: <"Charie">(name: "Charie") => void
```

The first two calls fail because when `T` is inferred to be the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Andy"` or `"Bob"`, then `T & Children` is possible, so `(T & Children) extends never` is false, and so `(T & Children) extends never ? T : never` is `never`, and so the arguments are rejected.

The second call succeeds because when `T` is inferred to be literal type `"Charlie"`, then `T & Children` is impossible, so `(T & Children) extends never` is true, and so `(T & Children) extends never ? T : never` is `T`, and so the argument is accepted.

So that looks good, so far.

---

Now for some more complicated situations:

```
func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "Andy" : "Charlie"); // error
// const func: <"Andy" | "Charlie">(name: never) => void
```

That fails because the argument is either `"Andy"` or `"Charlie"`, and since there is some overlap between `Children` and that type (namely `"Andy"`), then it is rejected.

Also rejected is an arbitrary `string`:

```
function foo(x: string) {
  func(x); // error, maybe it's "Andy" or "Bob"
  // const func: <string>(name: never) => void
}
```

because there's overlap between `string` and `Children` (namely, `Children`).  Note that the compiler and a human being might have a different view of what constitutes an "arbitrary" string.  If you use [the `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/plus) to concatenate strings, the compiler doesn't try to figure out what that might be, and just widens it to `string`.  So this is rejected:

```
func("Char" + "lie"); // error 
// const func: <string>(name: never) => void
```

*We* know that's `"Charlie"`, but the compiler doesn't, so it can't accept it.

On the other hand it *accepts* the following call:

```
function bar(x: `Char${string}`) {
  func(x); // okay, no way it can be "Andy" or "Bob"
  // const func: <`Char${string}`>(name: `Char${string}`) => void
}
```

The pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) `` `Char${string}` `` means "any string starting with `"Char"`".  The compiler understands that there is no overlap between such a type and `Children`, so it works.

Conversely the following fails:

```
function baz(x: `An${string}`) {
  func(x); // error
  // const func: <`An${string}`>(name: never) => void
}
```

because there is overlap between "strings that start with `"An"`" and `Children`, namely `"Andy"`.

So essentially, when in doubt, the compiler rejects the call.  That could make it somewhat difficult to use, since arbitrary `string` inputs are not accepted, but that's presumably what you want!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#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-LXbzDp6hVC+KLxfRrtLbJXfgASdLOnRZSuK5UXdjqqBPF46otll4t3ix7AGonFciWrbW20Mz4OtpyDcBtDbru+7TuuW47pOuj7nOYw+guS4PmYABea5QJWxCARBe4HhkR6qieEbVEsOoWAgOhwLwj7mjaJh2kyGy-uh4FDlhIHuvywyCjBQA)